# Calculating the surface integral between two paraboloids

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $E$ be the solid enclosed by the paraboloids $\ z = x^2+y^2$ and $\ z = 12 −2x^2−2y^2$
>   and let $S$ be the boundary of $E$ with outward pointing normal. Calculate $\iint_s F· dS$, where
>
> $$F(x, y, z)\ =\ \langle x^3+y^2, 2yz +e^z, y^2-z^2 \rangle$$

First, I decided to tackle the question using the Divergence Theorem.  $$
\int_ {-2}^2 \int_ {-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2} } \int_ {x^2+y^2}^{8-(x^2+y^2)} \ 3x^2 \ dz\ dy\ dx.
$$

So, I expressed the integral in spherical coordinates as:
$$3* \int_ 0^\pi \int_ 0^{2 \pi } \int_ 0^2 \rho^4 \sin^{3}\phi \cos^2\theta \ d\rho \ d\theta \ d\phi.$$

Both of the expressions above evaluate to different values that are not equal to the answer the professor provided, which is 48$\pi$.

Comment: I think limits for $\phi$ should be from $0$ to $\pi$/2..Also if u want to do in spherical coordinates you have to split integral up at point where two solids intersect as value of rho changes there. If would be much easier in cylindrical coordinated though

Comment: Also note value of phi will also change with rho

Comment: Are my limits in the rectangular coordinates correct though? because they give a value that disagrees with the answer I have

Comment: Your upper limit for z in rectangular coordinate should be $12 - 2x^{2} - 2y^2 $

Answer (score 1):

Your upper limit on the $z$-integral above should be $12-2(x^2+y^2)$. I get
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_{r^2}^{12-2r^2}3r^2\cos^2\theta\,dz\,r\,dr\,d\theta&=\frac12(2\pi)\int_0^23r^3(12-3r^2)dr\\
&=\pi\left[9r^4-\frac32r^6\right]_0^2=\pi\left[144-96\right]\\
&=48\pi\end{align}$$
Where I have used the average value of $\cos^2\theta$ of $\frac12$ to evaluate the azimuthal integral.